# Join Criteria into another Criteria on two properties

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Is there a way to join Criteria query into an existing one?

The actual query is a way more complicated and below is illustrating the simplified version of the problem.

```
Criteria c1 = session.createCriteria(A.class);
c1.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("x"))
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("y"))
    .add(Projections.sum("amount"))
);

Criteria c2 = session.createCritera(A.class);
//
// join on c2.x = c1.x AND c2.y = c1.y
//
```

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it creating an `Alias`. You can find some examples in the following [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) (*point 16.4. Associations*).

Hope this can help you.

Thanks